PDF Page Dimensions Wrong
I am using the geometry package to set smaller margins in my document, however the values by which I am adjusting margins seems to be making the page dimensions bigger when I download the pdf.
Is there any way to adjust margins while keeping the page dimensions appropriate for printing?
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


you have specified US Letter (default) paper with .75in margins (which means you have uncomfortably long text lines)  Given that you have the undefined option a4 (which would have generated a warning) I guess you intended to a4paper option, to get A4 paper with .75in margins?

@DavidCarlisle thank you so much! I usually copy the same template over and over so just forgot that the definition wasn't just a4.
